# Is time-series an appropriate method to model data sampled at widely irregular time intervals ?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, smoothing, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am relatively inexperienced with data analysis.

My question: Is time-series an appropriate method to fit trends to data sampled at widely-irregular time intervals such as forests of different ages sampled in a chronosequence? (The irregularity of the spacing is quite noticeable in my data, even visually, and it doesn't make sense to me to interpolate between measurements with this data).

A little context:
My objective is to select a relatively simple data analysis method that can fit trend lines to show the recovery of vegetation characteristics following forest harvest. Timber volume is shown here. This comes from a chronosquence dataset.

I am not really interested in projecting beyond my data. The main reason I am considering time-series is because of its relative simplicity and capability to handle the wide variety of probability distributions and trend shapes in my dataset of vegetation recovery.

[image: Example of the data I want to fit a trend line to. I also have multiple other scatterplots to fit trend lines to, which have different shapes and error distributions]

Comment: Most people here are not ecologists. "Chronosequence" is perhaps transparent, but for those new to the jargon I decode it as a series in space that can be treated as if it were a sequence in time (so, the hope is that other factors are approximately constant).

Comment: Thats correct. To elaborate on 'forest chronosequence,' the data is collected by sampling a series of forest patches found across a landscape, which are suspected to have different ages. Other environmental influences are controlled for through the process of site selection and thus are assumed to be constant. The forest age (which in my case is the explanatory variable) can only be accurately determined once on site by extracting tree cores from old trees and counting their annual growth rings, thus forest ages often end up being irregularly spaced in a forest chronosequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the well structured question.

While there are time-series methods which cater to irregular time-series, that doesn't really sound like the direction you need to go with this analysis. Time-series methods are usually employed when you need to account for time-varying model structure in a detailed way. From what you say, it seems you are looking to describe the general relationship between timber volume and stand age. You might want to look into non-linear regression using growth curve models, possibly with mixed-effects.

You might like to look at the Orange data set in R (see ?Orange and references therein) as an example of fitting a tree-growth model using nonlinear least squares. The nmle package is helpful for both nls and non-linear mixed effects models. [Forest Analytics with R](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~andrewpr/FAwR/index.html) may also be of interest to you.

Good Luck.

Comment: While using some regression models could be fine, probably you should account in some way for time dependence in the errors. You could look into robust standard errors!

Comment: Yes, the mixed-effects framework, and it's implementation on nmle, allows for incorporation of correlation structures so that time dependence can be handled appropriately.

Comment: I'd add that in a chronosequence no principle stops you having two measurements at the same "time". That's another reason why such data don't really fit into a time series framework. Time is in effect just another quantitative predictor here (or in some circumstances something you might want to predict by inverting a relationship).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think you are right, rather than treat it as a time-series, its better to treat forest age as a quantitative predictor variable of vegetation characteristics (eg timber volume). I am considering glm to fit the non-linear shape since with glm can accommodate the heterogeneity and non-normal error distributions in the data. I don't think there is temporal dependance since each forest patch is distinct and comes from its own location (see the comment I added to my own question). I could ask as a new question on this site if this might be an issue...